# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started: cannot load file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, apache2

I'm trying to set up a sinatra app via apache2 but I keep getting this error:

cannot load such file -- android_webservice.rb

where android_webservice.rb is my app.

This is my config.ru file

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'oci8'
require 'json'

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
disable :run, :reload

require 'android_webservice.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

I have also tried

```
require 'android_webservice'
```

I have respected the folder format:

my_webservice has the following files/folders:

```
/my_webservice/public
/my_webservice/tmp/restart
/my_webservice/config.ru
/my_webservice/my_app_files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `"./"`.

If your file is located in `/my_webservice/android_webservice.rb`, you must use:

```
require './android_webservice'
```